# What does the term “Jahreswagen” mean?

Tags: meaning

What does the term *Jahreswagen* mean? It literally translates to *year car.* In which context is it used?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The term **Jahreswagen** is used to describe a special kind of used cars.

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jahreswagen) states the term is appropriate as long the car’s date of first registration has not been longer than a year past today **and** production and registration date must be within a year.

These cars sometimes result of employees of car manufacturers might be allowed to buy a new car of their company every 12 months (Since they get a significant discount, the difference to the list price is relevant for income tax; they might sell it after the year for little less, than they paid for it.)

Another origin are company lease contracts for cars.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, a used car that's less than a year old.